# How many sql queries are fired when using Hibernate @ManyToMany annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have 2 classes, Parent and Child, both mapped with @ManyToMany annotation like this

```
class Parent 
{
   private int pid;
   private String pname;
   @ManyToMany
   private Collections<Child> child;
}
```

```
class Child
{
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy="child")
   private Collections<Parent> parent;
}
```

Now suppose I create the object of parent class only as follows

```
Parent p = new Parent();
```

Now obviously the child details won't be fetched since by default it is lazy loading.
**But my question here is that how many hibernate queries will be fired?**

As I can see these 2 things showing up in my console-

Hibernate: `alter table child add constraint (somestring) foreign key (parent_id) reference Parent (pid)`

Hibernate: `select parent0_.pid as pid1_0_0_, pname as pname2_0_0_, from Parent`

Comment: It depends on what you do. For instance, if the relation is lazy and your code never calls it (this is normal, not every method that works with *Parent* needs *Child*), then no SQL will be executed to load it. Provide the exact Java code. And since you have logging already activated, you will see that. Then why ask?

Comment: I asked because I don't understand why alter table query is fired. Is there any particular reason for that. And if there is then how can we change that.